# What is a single word for 'a descriptive list of stages'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes, as below, somebody will set out the 'stages' of some sort of life experience.

[image]

What is a single word for this collection of descriptive stages? I am not sure if a 'taxonomy' of stages is what I am after here. Can anyone help?

Comment: A _catalog_, maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about *progression*

> *progression*: the act or an instance of moving from one thing or unit in a sequence to the next ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/progression))
>
> A continuous series; a sequence. ([American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=progression))
>
> A succession. ([Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/progression))